# How to have the nav and footer more than 1000px?

Tags: html, css

My wrapper is 1000px. How can I have my nav bar and footer to be the whole page? If try taking nav and footer out of the wrapper nothing is being centered.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>  
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
}
body
{
background:white;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
}
#wrapper
{
 width:1000px;
 margin:2px auto 2px auto;
 text-align:left;
 }
```

Comment: please edit your question, its unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put nav and footer outside of wrapper. and:

```
#wrapper
{
 width:1000px;
 margin:2px auto 2px auto;
}

footer, #footer, .footer, nav .nav, #nav /* etc - whatever you're using */  {
 width:100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

If you want all content centered in these areas and not just text. Change the #wrapper to a class not an id ( .wrapper )and then add inside the footer or nav. e.g.

```
<footer>
 <div class='wrapper'>
  <!-- content here -->
 </div>
</footer>
```

Hope this answers your question as it is was a little unclear.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you will have to make the `#nav` and `#footer` outside of the the wrapper to make this easy on yourself. You give both of them the same properties as the `#wrapper` in the CSS then give `#nav` and `#footer` a width of 100%.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vBwq/). You will have to extend the window of the result to see it in action.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        Nav
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        Wrapper
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
body
{
  background:white;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:12px;
}
#wrapper, #nav, #footer
{
 width:1000px;
 margin:2px auto 2px auto;
 text-align:left;
 background-color: #eee;
 }

#nav, #footer {
 width: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is but try using the code below. I think this is what you want?

```
<style>*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
}
body
{
background:white;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
border: 2px solid #222;
min-height:600px;
}
#wrapper
{
 width:1000px;
 margin:2px auto 2px auto;
 text-align:left;
 border: 2px solid #000;
 min-height:300px;
 }

 footer{
 border: 2px solid red;
 }
 </style>
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>  
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    wrapper
    </div>
    <footer>
    footer
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry that I am not able to explain my problem right. Basically I want the navigation bar to extend more than 1000px. The body should only be 1000px. For example my website's nav bar looks like this. How can I extend the nav bar so that it will cover the whole page. http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1015?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F4&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=1